# Is it more effecient to use a class over an enum in typescript?

Tags: typescript, compiler-optimization

```
export class CarModels {
  public readonly Models: [] = ['chevy', 'ford'];
}

export enum CarModels {
  Models = 'chevy', 'ford'
}
```

what is more efficient for the typescript compiler and why? 
by efficient I mean overall performance of an application and compilation time.

could you please provide me with resources or a good explanation as to why it is more efficient?

Comment: By "more efficient for the compiler", do you mean a faster compilation time?

Comment: @Amy yes, and over all application performance.

Comment: If you have trouble with performance or desire improve it, profile your app and find what where and when overload occur, facing production scenario. solutions are often at a higher level of conception. To respond directly to your question, it is the same.